# At the same temperature, what's the relation of speed of heat loss between Earth and Mars?

Tags: mars, heat

Mars has a thinner athmosphere than Earth. Let's say you have a similar shelter of the same volume and made of the same materials in Mars at -70 Celsius, and in Earth in some place in the Antarctica also at -70 Celsius.  What would be the relation of speed of heat loss between the Earth shelter and the Mars shelter, considering heat loss by conduction and convection would be different in both places?

Comment: This is an interesting question, but it's more complicated than you might expect. In addition to heat exchange with the surface by conduction and with the atmosphere by convection, there is also the radiative pathway. A planet's atmosphere radiates heat towards the shelter and the shelter radiates heat into the atmosphere and into space. It's why clear nights can be colder than cloudy nights for example.